# Facing Option is not a constructor issue in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datatable.js

Few months back I have implemented the https://datatables.net/ jquery plugin in lightning component.

and created this https://github.com/RatanPaul/Salesforce-Lightning-Dynamic-Datatable package .

Now suddenly we are facing this issue like **Option is not a constructor**, I tried to find the solution for this issue but no luck.

[image]

Seems like at salesforce lightning side option constructor is different than datatable.js option

is there anyone faced this issue. Any fix for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue with Locker Service and the fix is expected to be deployed to Winter'17 on or around October 18th

Comment: Any news on that? I can still see it's present (EU6 dev sandbox)